# Divide a number into n unequal parts

Tags: javascript, math

I have a number N e.g. 100 and I want to divide it into n parts (e.g. 10 parts)

Doing this linearly is trivial - N/n and I get 10 parts each of the value 10.

However, I would like to do this so that the parts are unequal and increase exponentially. E.g.

10, 30, 60 so the total is 100.

How can I write this as a javascript function?

```js
function returnParts(desiredTotal, numParts) {
    ...
    return parts ///return an array of parts
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is some sort of distribution equation. This question would be better answered on the math stack overflow forum.

Comment: Just think how a binary, or any based number is represented in 10-base using the exponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is simple enough, when you allow floating point numbers:

```js
function getNums(n,f,tot){
let x=1;
 const arr=[...new Array(n)]
  .map(c=>x*=f);
 const mul=tot/arr.reduce((a,c)=>a+c);
 return arr.map(v=>mul*v)
}
 
console.log(getNums(3, 1.5, 100))
```

In order to get a unique result you need to specify the desired count `n` of numbers, the factor between the numbers `f` and the total `tot` the individual numbers must add up to.

And here is an adapted solution for integers:

```js
function getNums(n,f,tot){
let x=1,res;
 const arr=[...new Array(n)]
  .map(c=>x*=f);
 const mul=tot/arr.reduce((a,c)=>a+c);
 
 res=arr.map(v=>Math.round(mul*v));
 res[res.length-1]-=res.reduce((a,c)=>a+c)-tot;
 return res

}
const ar=getNums(3, 1.5, 100);
console.log(ar,ar.reduce((a,c)=>a+c))
```

@Redu provided a formula for calculating the sum of the series `2**i` for `n` values . By using the general annuity formula you will find that a suitable starting value `x` can be calculated through the following equation:

[image]

When I apply this formula I can save a few calculations in my script:

```js
// small utility function
function sum(a,c){return a+c}

// create a series of n integers with 
// factor b between them, having a total sum of tot:
function numSeries(b,n,tot){
 let x=tot*(1-1/b)/(b**n-1)

 const ar=[...new Array(n)]
  .map(_=>Math.round(x*=b) );
  // adjust the last number for rounding errors:
 ar[n-1]=tot-ar.slice(0,-1).reduce(sum);
 return ar;
}

// test it all:
const ar=numSeries(1.75,7,200);
console.log(ar,ar.reduce(sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Math problem. Once you solve it, implementing this with JS or any other language is just calculation.

So you want K numbers summing to T. However they will increase exponentially. Not so clear but from your given example lets assume our exponential series to be

```
T = x + 2x + 4x + 8x + ... + 2^(n-1) x
```

We can apply summing series trick here like

```
2T = 2x + 4x + 8x + ... + 2^n x
```

Now;

```
   2T = 2x + 4x + 8x + ... + 2^x
    T =  x + 2x + 4x + 8x + ... + 2^(n-1) x
(-)__________________________________
    T = 2^n x - x = (2^n - 1) x
```

So;

```
        T
x = _________
     2^n - 1
```

The JS part.

```js
function part(n,target){
  var x = target / (2**n-1);
  return Array.from({length:n}, (_,i) => x*2**i);
}

var result = part(6,100),
    sum    = result.reduce((p,c) => p+c);

console.log(result,sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. The exponential function is: A^numParts = desiredTotal. We first solve for A then push the values calculated values into the array. This works because the integral of an exponential function is the exponential function.

```js
function returnParts (desiredTotal, numParts) {
  var a = Math.pow(desiredTotal, 1/numParts)
  var parts = []
  for (var j = 0; j < numParts; j++) {
    var part = Math.pow(a, j + 1) - Math.pow(a, j)
    parts.push(part)
  }
  return parts
}
```

For example:

```js
var results = returnParts(1000, 3)
console.log(results)
//
//returns [9.999999999999998, 89.99999999999997, 909.9999999999994]
// which is equal to ~1000
//
```